# exit on ssh failure

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

in my play i ssh to a host and execute a number of roles, however if I fail to ssh into the instance the next include carry on regardless, id like to exit/fail when - build fails to execute

here is the example,

FYI - app_ec2 creates an instance on AWS and sets the host, build.yml then applies configuration to this instance and launch then users this instance to create an AMI and then a ASGroup

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: true
  any_errors_fatal: true
  max_fail_percentage: 0
  vars_files:
    - "vars/security.vars"
    - "vars/{{ env }}/common.vars"
    - "vars/server.vars"
  roles:
    - app_ec2

- include: build.yml
- include: launch-asg.yml
```

build.yml:

```
- hosts: "{{ role }}"                                                                                                                                                                                              
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: true
  sudo: yes
  any_errors_fatal: true
  max_fail_percentage: 0
  vars_files:
    - "vars/{{ env }}/common.vars"
    - "vars/server.vars"
  roles:
    - default
    - restart
    - awscli
    - cloudwatch-logs
    - ntp
    - java
    - tomcat
    - newrelic
    - newrelic_apm
    - "{{role}}"
    - app_liquibase
    - restart
```

Comment: can you provide a sample output and the contents of build.yml ?

Comment: - hosts: "{{ role }}"
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: true
  sudo: yes
  any_errors_fatal: true
  max_fail_percentage: 0
  vars_files:
    - "vars/{{ env }}/common.vars"
    - "vars/server.vars"
  roles:
    - default
    - restart
    - awscli
    - cloudwatch-logs
    - ntp
    - java
    - tomcat
    - newrelic
    - newrelic_apm
    - "{{role}}"
    - app_liquibase
    - restart

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you posted. I've simplified it a bit [here](https://gist.github.com/serialdoom/77e271410ea0ab2e2e3b242c5bc9e6fb) so i can test it and its failing for me. Can you provide a sample output run ?

Comment: Thank you, its the process of ssh to the host that doesn't fail, so using your example when ssh to execute bar1.yml fails bar.yml just goes ahead and plays and I would like the entire foo.bar to fail

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting to use [Ansible Blocks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html):

```
 tasks:
  - block:
      - debug: msg='i execute normally'
      - command: /bin/false
      - debug: msg='i never execute, cause ERROR!'
    rescue:
      - debug: msg='I caught an error'
      - command: /bin/false
      - debug: msg='I also never execute :-('
    always:
      - debug: msg="this always executes"
```

And you can use this workaround:

- Run some playbook on current host (-c local == local connection)
- Call
  inside some block run ansible that connects to remote host, and if
  block fails retry.

PS:

Ansible playbooks should use Idempotency concept:

> The concept that change commands should only be applied when they need
>   to be applied, and that it is better to describe the desired state of
>   a system than the process of how to get to that state. As an analogy,
>   the path from North Carolina in the United States to California
>   involves driving a very long way West but if I were instead in
>   Anchorage, Alaska, driving a long way west is no longer the right way
>   to get to California. Ansible’s Resources like you to say “put me in
>   California” and then decide how to get there. If you were already in
>   California, nothing needs to happen, and it will let you know it
>   didn’t need to change anything.